# In Couchbase Sync Gateway, how to make sure implicit OpenId implicit flow works?

Tags: openid-connect, auth0, couchbase-sync-gateway

I'm working on an application using OpenId connect implicit flow with Auth0 provider. I'm already able to get the JWT token from Auth0, and now want to start a session in Couchbase sync gateway.

For that, I do a POST to `/{db}/_session` which return me a cookie with `SyncGatewaySession` id. From what I understand, this should be associated with a user in sync gateway web interface ... However I see no user created.

So, is there a way to see which user I use for replication ?

Or a way to make sure my JWT token is correctly read by sync gateway ?

**EDIT** When I disable the GUEST user by setting the following in my config file,

```
        "users": {
            "GUEST": {
                "disabled": true,
                "admin_channels": [
                    "*"
                ]
            }
        }
```

my OpenId doesn't seem to access sync. I guess it means I use GUEST user unknowingly.

So. How can I have my OpenID user created as a distinct user from GUEST one ?

Comment: I am trying to integrate same, but it still fails to create proper session. If possible, can you update the answer with steps?

Comment: @dhaval you would better ask questions regarding specific points that doesn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are errors (and missing points) in Couchbase Sync gateway documentation for OpenId Connect implicit flow.

1. Id token MUST USE RS256 encoding algorithm
2. The public key used by the JWT provider must be used as `validation_key` defined in [Sync Gateway config file](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.4/guides/sync-gateway/config-properties/index.html).
3. To obtain a session, the JWT must be set as POST header with the key `Authorization` and the value prefix `Bearer`.
4. Then, to have users automatically created, the property `register` must be set to true in config file

With all those errors corrected, I finally had my users and sessions correctly created, and my couchbase lite data correctly replicated, even when users initially didn't exist.

Comment: hi can you help me? i have same problem.please help me.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63655700/how-to-make-sure-implicit-openid-implicit-flow-works-in-couchbase-sync-gateway